# How to pass user input to os command line interface using Python?

Tags: python, django

I am passing some user input to `views.py` file and need to pass those input param to OS command line interface using Python. I am providing my code below:

```
rname = request.POST.get('react')
        if 'strt' in request.POST:
            status = 1

        if 'shutbt' in request.POST:
            status = 0

        if 'susbtn' in request.POST:
            status = 2
passw = Reactor(
              rname=rname,
              status=status,
        )
passw.save()
```

Here I am getting the user input by `post` method and before save into database I need to pass both param `i.e-status and rname` to OS command line interface.

Comment: your indentation is really weird, but assuming it all works for you, i still don't understand your question... do you want to call a new command on the command line? You should use `subprocess.Popen` for that if yes.

Comment: Yes you are right . Can you share your idea ?

Comment: I did, my idea is that you should use `subprocess.Popen`: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html